# Removing last comma using sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a text file and I want to remove the last comma , from the second last line if exist.

```
a, b, c, d,
m, n, p,
x, y, z,
);
```

The comma after z needs be removed only.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will also like to know if it is possible to remove the last character on the last line. In this case the ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed 'N;$s/,\n/\n/;P;D' inputfile
```

It removes the comma from the end of the next-to-last line. This assumes that there is nothing after the last line you show.

If you need to key on the contents of that line instead, then this should work:

```
sed 'N;/)\;/s/,\n/\n/;P;D' inputfile
```

Comment: @shantanuo: To remove the comma as in the original *and* remove the final semicolon, try this: `sed 'N;/)\;/s/,\\(\n.*\\).$/\1/;P;D'` (or `sed 'N;/)\;/s/,\\(\n.*\\);$/\1/;P;D'`)

Comment: Your second suggestion doesn't actually work for me, though the first does.

Comment: @Clayton: Do you mean the comma after the "z" is still there? By "second suggestion" do you mean in the answer or one of the ones in the comment? If you mean the ones in the comment are giving you an error, then change the double backslashes to single ones. I evidently made a mistake in posting them and trying to make the markdown syntax work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with awk:

```
 awk 'l2{print l2} {l2=l1; l1=$0} END{sub(/,$/,"",l2); print l2 "\n" l1}' file
```